# Conflicting key bindings in Visual Studio Code extensions

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

Many vscode extensions have some similar generic functionality, for example, a preview. So, they map this preview to suitable key bindings (`Ctrl-Shift-V` `Ctrl-K-V`). But these bindings might cause conflicts in the case of multiple extensions. Markup, asciidoc, gpx files and possibly html in my case.

On the other hand, to have the same binding for the same functionality is preferable. Is there some concept of *'scope'* with the meaning of limiting a binding to a specific extension/file-type context, allowing parallel use of the same keys in different contexts?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code has no concept of shortcuts context, other than limiting them
to the text editor or other module.

It can help with
[Detecting keybinding conflicts](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_detecting-keybinding-conflicts).

Use the Keyboard Shortcuts editor and the context menu command
*Show Same Keybindings*, which will filter the keybindings based on a
keyboard shortcut to display conflicts.

There was a request for improvement at
[Option to find conflicting (duplicate) keyboard shortcuts #33745](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/33745),
but that request wasn't accepted by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are [when clause contexts](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_when-clause-contexts) that can be applied to keybindings.

The [Keyboard Shortcuts editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) shows the context for all available key bindings in the "When" column:
[image: Keyboard Shortcuts]

Extension authors should ensure any keybindings their extension defines are limited to the smallest possible context to help minimize conflicts.  For example, an extension that provides Markdown preview should use keybindings like this:

```javascript
{
    ...
    "keybindings": [
        {
            "command": "less-annoying-markdown-preview.openPreview",
            "key": "ctrl+shift+v",
            "mac": "cmd+shift+v",
            "when": "editorFocus && editorLangId == markdown"  // <-- this is important!
        },
    ],
    ...
}
```

If you find an extension that doesn't have the correct contexts set, you should be helpful by submitting a pull request to fix the context (instead of being lazy and just raising an issue complaining of the problem, which contributes to developer burnout).